# Inserting ISODate field through azure stream analytics to MongoDB as a service in CosmosDB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-cosmosdb

I'm inserting documents into MongoDB (as a service in CosmosDB) through the azure stream analytics job.
Everything works well except for time fields that arrive to the database as a string instead of date-time fields.

The problem is that azure stream analytics works only with valid JSON formats, while mongoDB accepts a format that is a bit different.

Currently this is the JSON message that is sent:

```
{
   "Time" : "08/16/2017 19:20:00"
}
```

While MongoDB should get this:

```
{
   "Time" : ISODate("08/16/2017 19:20:00")
}
```

I'm unable to generate the ISODate syntax through stream analytics because it is not a valid json format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this link](https://www.compose.com/articles/from-json-to-bson-and-back/) which might help you. You would need to send your dates as the milliseconds since the 1970 epoch, instead of as a string. So the valid json you would sent to mongo would be something like:

```
{
   "Time" : { "$date": 1502904000000 }
}
```

Edit:

user2681670 used the following working solution:

```
{
   "Time" : { "$date": "2017-09-19T06:59:27.000Z"}
}
```

Comment: That is not actually true. The context of the "link" is  referring to [MongoDB Extended JSON syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/), which "may" be supported in "some" drivers by a specific JSON parse method. However the general approach in most languages is to simply to parse the value into a supported `Date` type. All drivers use the "lingua franca" or "commonly used" `Date` type to form a BSON Date which will be inserted into the document. You seem to be under the common misconception that MongoDB stores "JSON" data. It does not.

Comment: I don't really get your comment. I know that mongo stores BSON and not JSON, but OP needed to send valid JSON, so that's why I suggested this.

Comment: MongoDB does not store JSON. You can "parse JSON" to native data structures and "insert" that to MongoDB where the driver takes care of the "native data" to BSON conversion. But it's not JSON.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved. 
I was able to use a regular date format and not the 1970 epoch with the following syntax:

{
   "Time" : { "$date": "2017-09-19T06:59:27.000Z"}
}

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, I'll edit my answer.